# pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish token value 'does not start with "pypi-"'

Tags: python, github-actions

I am trying to use the `pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish` action in GitHub to push a Python package to PyPI. I'm in the team that owns [microbiomedata/nmdc-schema](https://github.com/microbiomedata/nmdc-schema) and successfully uses a [GitHub action](https://github.com/microbiomedata/nmdc-schema/blob/main/.github/workflows/pypi-publish.yml) to deploy the [nmdc-schema](http://https:/https://pypi.org/project/nmdc-schema/). I have also read [PyPA's advice](https://packaging.python.org/guides/publishing-package-distribution-releases-using-github-actions-ci-cd-workflows/) and tried to follow it precisely.

However, when it comes to authenticating against PyPI, I get [this](https://github.com/turbomam/linkml-template-audit/runs/3145695841?check_suite_focus=true#step:7:24) "no matter what I do"

```
Run pypa/gh-action-pypi-publish@v1.2.2
  with:
    user: __token__
    password: ${ secrets.pypi_password }
    packages_dir: dist
    verify_metadata: true
  env:
    pythonLocation: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.11/x64
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.11/x64/lib
/usr/bin/docker run --name a33c111d135a08e424daf8f55d57f9438a27b_084f0c --label 8a33c1 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e pythonLocation -e LD_LIBRARY_PATH -e INPUT_USER -e INPUT_PASSWORD -e INPUT_REPOSITORY_URL -e INPUT_PACKAGES_DIR -e INPUT_VERIFY_METADATA -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_ACTION_REF -e GITHUB_PATH -e GITHUB_ENV -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/linkml-template-audit/linkml-template-audit":"/github/workspace" 8a33c1:11d135a08e424daf8f55d57f9438a27b  "__token__" "${ secrets.pypi_password }" "" "dist" "true"
Warning:  It looks like you are trying to use an API token to authenticate in the package index and your token value does not start with "pypi-" as it typically should. This may cause an authentication error. Please verify that you have copied your token properly if such an error occurs.
Checking dist/linkml_template_audit-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl: PASSED, with warnings
  warning: `long_description_content_type` missing. defaulting to `text/x-rst`.
Checking dist/linkml_template_audit-0.0.1.tar.gz: PASSED, with warnings
  warning: `long_description_content_type` missing. defaulting to `text/x-rst`.
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Uploading linkml_template_audit-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl

  0%|          | 0.00/29.6k [00:00<?, ?B/s]
 27%|██▋       | 8.00k/29.6k [00:00<00:00, 48.7kB/s]
100%|██████████| 29.6k/29.6k [00:00<00:00, 107kB/s] 
NOTE: Try --verbose to see response content.
HTTPError: 403 Forbidden from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more information.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only wrapping my PyPI secret token in one pair of curly brackets! Two are required, like

`${{ secrets.nmdc_schema_pypi_token }}`

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was that I added secrets as "environment secret" rather than "repository secret", leaving the latter empty.

Answer (score 0):

This happened for me in the following circumstances:

- Forked a project in github
- Added a secret for the fork
- Pushed update to my fork, and created a PR
- The PR action ran in the upstream project
- Build failed, with the "does not start with pypi" error

Instead I created a branch directly in the upstream project (along with the secret token), and when I pushed the branch to the upstream project, it ran as expected and updated TestPyPi.